# How can I check texallcaps is true/false for Editext/TextView in Android at run time?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-textattributes

I have set android:textAllCaps="true" for a TextView for displaying label in capital letters. Its displaying fine.
 But, I need to check at run time, whether the label is in Capital or not. But, I could not able to find the property for getting textAllCaps attribute. Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you check the TextView/ Button source code, found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java)

The setAllCaps method sets a transformation method to the corresponding view using the `setTransformationMethod` method.

Which is `AllCapsTransformationMethod` for the `setAllCaps` method. Thus to get whether the view is set or not you can check using this:

```
    TransformationMethod transformationMethod = btn.getTransformationMethod();
    if (transformationMethod!=null){
      if (transformationMethod.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(AllCapsTransformationMethod.class.getSimpleName())){
//        todo logic based code
      }
```

Where btn is your button view

Or alternatively make a method out of it to check if the Button/TextView has all caps value set or not

Something like this:

```
public boolean hasAllCaps(TextView textView){  
 TransformationMethod transformationMethod = textView.getTransformationMethod();
    if (transformationMethod!=null)
      if (transformationMethod.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(AllCapsTransformationMethod.class.getSimpleName())){
            return true;
      }
return false;
}
```

And then just check the value!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on why you would want to check them even though it's sure that they would be in caps due to the **textAllCaps** attribute.

A workaround would be to get the **Text** of the **TextView** then compare it with the uppercase of that text:

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
if(text.equals(text.toUpperCase()){
    \\The text is in Uppercase
}
```

Comment: textview.getText() always returns the format(E.g text label: Open), which we maintained in strings.xml. I need to display in all caps. So, I'm using the textAllCaps attribute, Since I may need to use that label in some other places. For Automation purpose, we need to validate from the code that whether the text is in allCaps. If I'm keeping the label as "OPEN" in strings.xml, getText() working fine. The problem is , I couldn't validate textAllCaps @run time

Comment: If that's the case, then I think you could set the labels programatically? Use the Resource class to get them and then set them to the TextView using the String toUpperCase() method. That way, when you do the Automated Validations, the getText() method would return a String in uppercase.